# Changing the view of the Calendar Component

Tags: sxa

I'm using SXA event calendar component from tool box and I'm trying to figure out whether its possible to change the view of the event calendar component using its out-of-the-box features. Is there a way to add a "create event" button in calendar view where I can add an event on a specific day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few notes which might help you:

1. Yes, you can completely change the view of the rendering. SXA has clone rendering feature which allows you to clone existing rendering and provide a path to the updated/new *.cshtml view.

   [image]
2. SXA is using [FullCalendar.js](https://fullcalendar.io/) plugin to display the calendar. You can read the documentation and see what is possible there in context of front-end UI changes. You will find the initialization of the calendar in `component-fullcalendar.js` (for the Wireframe theme this file is attached to this item: `/sitecore/media library/Themes/Wireframe/scripts/component-fullcalendar`). You can modify this as you want to keep in mind that this is SXA item and will be overridden while updating SXA to next version (would be better to have an extension theme).

Modify, play with it, have fun!

Comment: In order to modify the component-fullcalendar.js, should i download it, modify it and then re uploaded it again to the same theme??
@DawidRutkowski

Comment: Yes. But please remember that when you will upgrade to next version of SXA this item will be overridden.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, i did an upgrade first and also i modified in another theme not the Wireframe one.
Please, do you have any idea after cloning the rendering and making it point to a different view(.cshtml) file, how can i select the calendar using jQuery selector inorder to add something to the view, for example adding a text or custom button?

Comment: Do you have any idea where can i find the core javascript (fullcalendar.js) so that i can modify it?

Comment: Here: /sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Core Libraries/scripts/fullcalendar